# Starting OpenOffice from applet

Tags: java, applet, openoffice.org

I have this code down and this working fine from command line ...
But when I put this in applet I get following error

com.sun.star.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at com.sun.star.comp.bridgefactory.BridgeFactory.createBridge(BridgeFactory.java:158)
    at
com.sun.star.comp.urlresolver.UrlResolver$_UrlResolver.resolve(UrlResolver.java:130)

Anybody have solution for this problem ? Where I can  find BridgeFactory source ?

```
   Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:/Program Files/OpenOffice.org 3/program/soffice.exe -accept=socket,host=localhost,port=8100;urp;StarOffice.ServiceManager"); // oooUrlW - the url of soffice.exe
              Thread.sleep(5000);

              XComponentContext xLocalContext = com.sun.star.comp.helper.Bootstrap.createInitialComponentContext(null);
              XMultiComponentFactory xLocalServiceManager = xLocalContext.getServiceManager();
              Object urlResolver  = xLocalServiceManager.createInstanceWithContext("com.sun.star.bridge.UnoUrlResolver",xLocalContext);
              XUnoUrlResolver xUnoUrlResolver = (XUnoUrlResolver) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XUnoUrlResolver.class,urlResolver);

              Object initialObject = xUnoUrlResolver.resolve("uno:socket,host=localhost,port=8100;urp;StarOffice.ServiceManager");
              XPropertySet xPropertySet = (XPropertySet) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XPropertySet.class,initialObject);
              XComponentContext remoteContext = (XComponentContext) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XComponentContext.class, xPropertySet.getPropertyValue("DefaultContext"));

              XMultiComponentFactory remoteServiceManager = remoteContext.getServiceManager();
              Object desktop = remoteServiceManager.createInstanceWithContext("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop", remoteContext);

                 xDesktop =(XDesktop) UnoRuntime.queryInterface( XDesktop.class, desktop);
 XComponent xCalcComponent =
           newDocComponent(xDesktop, "scalc");
           XSpreadsheetDocument xCalcDocument =
                      (XSpreadsheetDocument)UnoRuntime.queryInterface(
                                           XSpreadsheetDocument.class, xCalcComponent);
           XSpreadsheets a=xCalcDocument.getSheets();
           Object o = a.getByName("Sheet1");

           XSpreadsheet sheet = (XSpreadsheet)UnoRuntime.queryInterface(
                    XSpreadsheet.class, o);


           XCell jjjj = sheet.getCellByPosition(0, 0);
           jjjj.setFormula("Some Text ");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is signed, and I found kind of solution - on client I grant
  `permission java.security.AllPermission;` and now everything work...
I still did'nt try grant SignedBy "MyCompany" permission java.securyty.AllPermission 
which I must do...

Error message is misleading me 
  com.sun.star.lang.IllegalArgumentException   ... stupid message

I must use applet ... it is Oracle Forms application and I need to start Calc on client and fill some data.

Thanks on help.

Answer (score 1):

Is your applet **signed** ? else I don't think you can call

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:/Program Files/OpenOffice.org 3/program/soffice.exe-accept=socket,host=localhost,port=8100;urp;StarOffice.ServiceManager");
```

from an applet.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Pierre... you would need a trusted/signed applet to do that. You might also want to reconsider why you are trying to do this with an applet rather than a standalone application (using webstart or something if you need to web-deliverable).

One more thing to consider is that the end-user would have to have OpenOffice installed locally (unless they have changed the way their API works) for any Java-OO.o access to work correctly. This requirement may have changed though, it has been a while since I have played around with their API.

Good luck and I hope this helps a little.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple way to place OOo in an applet - use the [OfficeBean](http://api.openoffice.org/docs/DevelopersGuide/OfficeBean/OfficeBean.xhtml)

While you'll still have your java security problem, your code will be a lot tighter. We're using this to do the same thing.  My post on how to get OO 3.2 working in Java 6 applets is [here](http://the-music-of-time.blogspot.com/2010/01/openoffice-311-in-java-6-applet.html) is you want to take a look.  It works for 3.1 and 3.2.